# No data received even though topics are not empty

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using RTABmap and having a camera on a seperate machine which sends image_rect/compressed over the WiFi to my host PC. My tree looks very standard and non-broken and every topic is not empty, they are published but when I try to run rtabmap I get this error:

```
[ WARN] [1553595152.413459752]: /rtabmap/rtabmapviz: Did not receive data since 5 seconds! Make sure the input topics are published ("$ rostopic hz my_topic") and the timestamps in their header are set. If topics are coming from different computers, make sure the clocks of the computers are synchronized ("ntpdate"). If topics are not published at the same rate, you could increase "queue_size" parameter (current=10).
/rtabmap/rtabmapviz subscribed to (approx sync):
   /odom,
   /duo3d/left/image_rect_relay,
   /duo3d/right/image_rect_relay,
   /duo3d/left/camera_info,
   /duo3d/right/camera_info
```

Why is it stating that? I have every topic that is mentioned above and running at the same 30hz rate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319547/no-data-received-even-though-topics-are-not-empty/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-03-26**:
What is the output of `echo $ROS_MASTER_URI` for each machine ?

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-03-26**:
@Delb on my embedded machine it is:
http://HOSTPC_IP:11311/
On my host pc:
http://localhost:11311

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-03-31**:
Which node is publishing /odom? Are the stamps matching between odom and the image topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set `ROS_MASTER_URI` to the ip address of the computer running `roscore` on both machines. For example, if you run `roscore` on your host pc, you should then do on your embedded machine :

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://HOSTPC_IP:11311/
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-03-26**:
Thanks for the answer, but how then I worked before? I did not set that on my host pc and sometimes I did manage RTABMAP to work

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-03-26**:
You mean it was working before without setting those parameters ? On which machine were you usually running roscore ?

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-03-26**:
@Delb Yes, I used the same machine